# Service и Activity. Передача данных при перезапуске приложения.

Tags: android, service

Всем привет!
Разрабатываю приложение-таймер, который считает, например, 5 минут, по прошествии 5 минут открывает окно, в котором нужно написать, что вы делали эти 5 минут.
Столкнулся со следующей задачей - запускаю приложение, все хорошо, 5 минут тикают. Если сворачиваю приложение и начинаю выполнять другие тяжелые операции, то система убивает мое приложение.
Все напишут, что тут нужно писать сервис. И я пришел к такому же решению - написал сервис, который висит в статус баре, и если приложение убивается системой, то сервис продолжает жить и время тикает.
Вопрос в следующем - в статус баре висит Notification от сервиса. Предположим, что система убила мое приложение. Я тыкаю по Notifiaction и мне нужно, чтобы сервис передал все свои отработанные данные в заново запустившееся приложение. Как это сделать?
BroadcastReceiver, PendingIntent, может быть - есть другие какие-то варианты?

Comment: Приложение при onResume подписывается на BroadcastReceiver и получает актуальные данные. При onPause - отписывается.

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь пример рабочего кода? Можно на английском, с ним у меня проблем нет.

Comment: Начните с этого - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html